# Comparing if new date matches date in database then redirecting to matching edit page in mvc2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio-2010

You start at create page then select a date via datepicker and submit, now I want it not to create a new edit page with blank details but instead redirect to an existing edit page based on if the date selected matches a date recorded in the database.

I have 3 forms on same page with each being filled at different times of the day and once saved they are read only display views.

added comparing to title to indicate this topic wasn't about redirecting.

Comment: So anybody know then how to compare the date a action would receive to all possible dates in a sql database which if it helps is connected up with an edmx?

Answer (score 0):

All this would involve is you doing your date comparison in your action and then calling [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28VS.90%29.aspx) like `RedirectToAction("actionNameToRedirectTo")` or if you want to include a model with that redirect using `RedirectToAction("actionToRedirectTo", model)`

Comment: I figured that much out but I didn't know how to do the comparison hence me marking this with c# tags so if someone was going to type an example they wouldn't do it in vb.